# Безопасно ли открывать публично FORWARD цепочку в iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

Я настраиваю iptables в цели защиты хоста от атак, INPUT цепочку я практически закрыл, оставил только самое необходимое. А вот нужно ли закрывать FORWARD?

Comment: Если ваш хост не роутер, то форвард можно отключить через sysctl

Comment: Если за вашей машиной кто-то есть (или даже виртуальные машины не в режиме моста), то надо смотреть, в противном случае никакой разницы нет.